# Show that $x$ and $Q x$ are equidistant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

$$Q= \begin{bmatrix} \cos x & -\sin x\\ \sin x & \cos x\end{bmatrix}$$

Given x belongs to $\mathbb{R^2}$, show $Qx$ and $x$ are equidistant.

I've tried dot producting $Qx$ and seeing whether they are equal. I just can't seem to get it.

Comment: $Q$ is not even a point. Are you maybe trying to show that $x$ and $Qx$ share the same length? I.e. Are equidistant from $0$?

Comment: Yes, from the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, we can easily prove that $Q $ is an orthogonal matrix, i.e. $Q^{-1} = Q^T$. Now, for every orthogonal matrix we have that $\|Qx\| = \|x \|$.

**Proof:**

$$\|Qx\|^2 =(Qx)^T (Qx) = x^TQ^TQx = x^T(Q^TQ) x = x^TIx = x^Tx= \|x\|^2$$

Comment: Why does ∥Qx∥^2=(Qx)^T(Qx)? Is that a property?

I assume ∥Qx∥^2 is the distance from the centre?

Comment: Well, if you have a vector $\vec x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix} $, then 
$$\vec x^T \cdot \vec x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix}= x_1^2 + x_2^2 +\cdots + x_n^2 = \|\vec x\|^2 .$$ 
$Qx$ is also a vector and the same thing applies. Moreover, $\|Qx\|$ is the magnitude (or absolute value or norm) of the vector $Qx$.  

You can think of the magnitue of a vector $\vec x$ as the distance of the point $ (x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n)$ from the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, @thanasissdr answer is the well educated one, but arguing more naïvely:

As written in my comment:
$$d((a,b),(0,0)=\sqrt{(a-0)^2+(b-0)^2}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\|(a,b)\|$$

Thus we compare the norms.

We have:

$$\|(a,b)\|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
and
\begin{align*}\|Q(x,y)\|& =\|(\cos(x)a+\sin(x)b,-\sin(x)a+\cos(x)b)\|\\ & =\sqrt{(\cos(x)a+\sin(x)b)^2+(-\sin(x)a+\cos(x)b)^2}\\ & =\sqrt{\cos^2(x)a^2+\sin^2(x)b^2+2\sin(x)\cos(x)ab\cos^2(x)b^2+\sin^2(x)a^2\color{red}{-}2\sin(x)\cos(x)ab}\\ & =\sqrt{[\sin^2(x)+ \cos^2(x)]a^2+[\sin^2(x)b^2+\cos^2(x)]b^2}\\ & =\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\end{align*}
as claimed, where we have used the classic identity $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$.

Note: Any matrix $Q$ which fulfills this property is called orthogonal matrix. This is equivalent to the above cited criterion $Q^\top Q=1$.

Answer (score 0):

[Kuldeep Singh's *Linear Algebra: Step by Step*](https://maths-for-all.co.uk/linear-algebra/)
(2013) p 327 details this more.

[image]

There's a typo. "Exercise 4" ought "Exercise 9".

Unlike other textbooks, [Singh gainfully posted all solutions](https://global.oup.com/booksites/content/9780199654444/studentsolutions)!

[image]